# REGEXP_LIKE syntax equivalent to access LIKE query

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I have an access query I need to convert to a standard oracle SQL statement.
The Access query has Like statement structured as

Like "[ABCDEFGH]##[ABCDEF]##"

Which translates to anything Starting with A-H with two numeric digits followed by the letter A-F ending with two numeric digits.

Query would pull results similar to "A01A01" for example.

I experimented with different regexp_like expressions but cannot clearly understand the syntax to pull off something similar.

Comment: I don't think that MySQL supports `regexp_like()`.

Comment: Its intended for oracle sql statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent regular expression is `^[A-H][0-9]{2}[A-F][0-9]{2}$'`.

I am not aware the MS Access supports this in any way.

Comment: This worked as expected thanks for the quick reply.